# How to combine 3 terms in elasticsearch?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I got a search that needs to combine three different terms on my user:

`user_locked? || (user_expired? && !user_granted?)`

This is what I got now but it throws an error message:

```
query do
  bool do
    must { match_all {} }
    filter do
      bool do
        should { term(user_locked: true) }
        minimum_should_match { 1 }
      end
      bool do
        filter do
          term(user_expired: true)
          term(user_granted: false)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

error message:

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'filter' for #<Elasticsearch::DSL::Search::Filters::Bool`

Any idea how to solve this or maybe even a better query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
query do
  bool do
    minimum_should_match 1
    should do
      term(user_locked: true)
    end
    should do
      bool do
        must do
          term(user_expired: true)
        end
        must do
          term(user_granted: false)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

According to your second comment, we need to NEGATE your condition, i.e.

`!(user_locked? || (user_expired? && !user_granted?))`

which is now equivalent to

`!user_locked? && (!user_expired? || user_granted?)`

which translates to

```
query do
  bool do
    must do
      term(user_locked: false)
    end
    must do
      bool do
        minimum_should_match 1
        should do
          term(user_expired: false)
        end
        should do
          term(user_granted: true)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

That query will now return documents with `user_locked: false, user_expired: false` as expected

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion but it does return 0 users and there's all kinds of users (locked, unlocked, expired, granted, ...). Does this query maybe ignore `user_locked: false, user_expired: false` users? This is the default state.

Comment: `user_locked: false, user_expired: false` would not be returned since we're looking for either locked users or expired ones who are not granted access.

Comment: Then I may have described it wrongly, let me try that again: `I want to see all users EXCEPT user_locked: true OR (user_expired:true AND user_granted: false)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update, unfortunately it is still not returning the right users :( It is not returning users with all attributes set to `false`

Comment: What users are returned that should not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138243/discussion-between-cojones-and-val).

Answer (score 0):

I use `chewy` gem with elasticsearch, but you can adapt this for DSL. I have not tested it, but I think it should work:

```
   index.query(
     bool: {
       must: { match_all: {} },
         filter: {
           bool: {
             should: [
               {term: { user_locked: false}},
               bool: {
                 must: [
                   { term: { user_expired: false} },
                   { term: { user_granted: true } }
                 ]
                },
              minimum_should_match: 1
              ]
            }
          }
       }
     )
```